# How to fix a memoryleak in a multipage silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, memory-leaks

L.S.,

I am building an application. The application consists of two screens. On the first screen the user can select a file, on the second the file is displayed with a chart and a data grid.

At the moment I have two big issues with this application.

The first issue is that the binding of the data to the chart takes very long (if the data set is 85 items the binding time can take up to 40 seconds).

The second issue is that when I go back from the second page to the first page the second page is not disposed. It continues to use up memory. This in turn will have effect on the first issue, making the binding time even longer.

Can anybody help me with this problem? (with clear code examples)

I use the following code to switch screens:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="NavigationGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="LightGray">
        <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link1" Width="100" Height="30" NavigateUri="/Home" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="Home" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel2" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100,0,0,0">
            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link2" Width="100" Height="30" NavigateUri="/DataPage" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="DataPage" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Margin="0,30,0,0">
        <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Source="/Home" >
            <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                </uriMapper:UriMapper>
            </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The code for the first page is not very important. It contains a select field where you can select a filename which will be opened in the second page. I made a test application and left this page empty and it still got the memory leak.

The code of the second page is:

```
    public partial class DataPage : Page
{
    private List<Classes.Data> dataList = new List<Classes.Data>();
    public DataPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setData(); //Get data, normaly from database.
        MainDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataList; //Bind data from datalist to datagrid
        bindChart(); //Bind data from datalist to chart.
    }
    private void setData()
    {
        Classes.Data data = new Classes.Data() { distance = 1, name = "First item", var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3, var4 = 4, var5 = 5 };
        dataList.Add(data);
        data = new Classes.Data() { distance = 1.5, name = "Second item", var1 = 1.5, var2 = 2.5, var3 = 3.5, var4 = 4.5, var5 = 5.5 };
        dataList.Add(data);
        data = new Classes.Data() { distance = 2, name = "Third item", var1 = .5, var2 = 1.5, var3 = 2.5, var4 = 3.5, var5 = 4.5 };
        dataList.Add(data);
        data = new Classes.Data() { distance = 2.5, name = "Fourth item", var1 = 3, var2 = 4, var3 = 5, var4 = 6, var5 = 7 };
        dataList.Add(data);
        data = new Classes.Data() { distance = 3, name = "Fifth item", var1 = 0, var2 = 1, var3 = 2, var4 = 3, var5 = 4 };
        dataList.Add(data);
    }
    private void bindChart()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //Bind each Lineseries to datalist.
            LineSeries lineSeries = (LineSeries)dataChart.Series[i];
            lineSeries.ItemsSource = dataList;
        }
    }

    private void backBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Home home = this.Parent as Home; //Get parent.
        home.Change_ContentFrame(new Home()); //Set parent to new page.
    }

    //Data grid events. - Start.
    private void MainDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void MainDataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void MainDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void MainDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //Data grid events. - End.
    //Data chart events. - Start.
    private void dataChart_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void dataChart_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void dataChart_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //Data chart events. - End.
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have 2 pages and a usercontrol for naviagtion and the code you provided is on your user control.  Can you provide code from your 2 pages, where the problem is, so we can attempt to help you with this?

Comment: I have added the code of the second page.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Maybe your issue is related to how you are navigating. It looks like you are calling and event handler instead of the way it should be done. The way I learn to use the `navigation:Frame` is to call it's navigate method. IE, `ContentFrame.Navigate(New Uri("/" & PageName, UriKind.Relative))`. I think you might be able to call that in your case using `home.ContentFrame.Navigate(New Uri("/" & PageName, UriKind.Relative))` but I also like to create a Public method on my main page that I call so I can handle validation and stuff before I navigate.  Not sure if this is your issue but it could be.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried it and sadly it didn't fix the memory leak. I think the leak is based on the chart not being disposed properly when I leave the page, keeping its data in it's memory. Any ideas how to fix that?